# invoke javascript expression

Tags: javascript, function, expression, execute

I have tried below two javascript functions in chrome via developer tool however I thought second function would be invoked when js interpreter reaches it but didn't. Not sure why.

```
var x = function() { console.log("probably not invoked."); }

var x = function() { console.log("probably invoked."); };

x(); // I had to do this to invoke the function
```

The reason behind of testing this is I was using XmlHttpRequest first time while reading property name status of the object I ran into a piece of code as below I was told that onreadystatechange function pointer will be executed so I thought having semicolon on anonymous function would be executed when js interpreter reaches it?

```
function makeRequest() {
    .....
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = (xhr.status == 200) ? "status good" : "status bad";
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XMLHttpRequest object will look for a function stored in `onreadystatechange` and call it when the ready state changes.

It is the event firing that triggers the function being called, not the assignment itself.

This is akin to

```
document.body.onclick = function () { alert("You clicked!"); };
```

The semi-colon on the end is just the regular semi-colon that you (should) put after every JavaScript statement.